# Tengo un generador de códigos QR en Python que guarda el enlace de 1 aplicación web Django. ¿Cómo puedo identificar de dónde se escaneó el código QR?

Tags: python, django, qt-designer

Estoy trabajando con Modelform en Django, en el campo de sala quiero que mediante diferentes códigos QR se identifique de donde se envía la orden

```
class Order(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   email = models.EmailField()
   address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   sala = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = numero_sala, blank=False, null=True,)
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con saber de dónde se ha escaneado? Si te estoy entendiendo bien, quizás puedas agregar a ese QR un parámetro adicional que diga "ubicacion" y le asignas algún valor como "almacen1", "almacen2", "gerencia", de tal forma que cuando hagan el escenaeo, puedas recibir ese parámetro y ya sabrías de dónde se ha escenado, ahora, si te refieres a querer saber ubicación exacta, podrías intentar pedir geolocalización para dar acceso a la lectura del QR. Si buscas algo diferente, agrega mayores detalles en tu pregunta, colocar el escenario sirve mucho :D

Comment: Suponiendo que el QR tiene una URL que tu controlas, y lo que quieres saber es si se escaneo en un dispositivo móvil, en una PC o en una tablet, puedes analizar el encabezado `User-Agent` de la petición HTTP(S), del cual puedes derivar información como el navegador, sistema operativo, etc. Eso si, nada te garantiza que cada _hit_ a esa URL venga del código QR, alguien pudo simplemente escribir la dirección en un navegador, o copiar y pegar, copiar y enviar por whatsapp, que se yo...

Comment: amigo @fredyfx exactamente como expones en la primera opción, por ejemplo tengo en un mismo lugar unas 8 -10 o cualquier numero de areas, y en el momento de escanear el código QR, me reporte esa información en el admin de Django. Si me podrías ayudar

Comment: Básicamente un QR es la codificación de una cadena de texto, por lo tanto si tienes una URL que diga `https://sistemadeventas.com/?ubicacion=almacen1&producto=123&algunOtroParametro=algunOtroValor`, esto será un QR, al momento de escanearlo, simplemente tendrás un "GET" del lado del servidor, en ese GET, es donde tienes que leer la variable `ubicacion`, ¿sí me dejo entender?

Comment: Gracias amigo @fredyfx me ayudaste con lo que necesitaba.... espero pases bien

Comment: Perfecto, éxitos y recuerda dar una lectura al recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y de paso una lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822